# Test method existence on Objects

Tags: oop, matlab

I have a cell array of `Matlab` objects, something like:

```
objs = {Object1(), Object2(), Object3()};
```

These objects are all of different types. Some of them will have a method, let's call it `myMethod()`. I want to do something like:

```
for o = objs
  if hasMethod(o, 'myMethod()')
    o.myMethod();
  end
end
```

and my difficulty is that I don't know how to do `hasMethod` - `exist` doesn't seem helpful here.

I could use a `try - catch`, but I'd rather do something neater. Is there a way to do this? Should I just change my design instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the meta class.

```
  obmeta = metaclass(ob);
  methodNames = cellfun(@(x){x.Name},obmeta.Methods);
```

You can also get additional information from `obmeta.Methods` like

- Amount of input/output parameters.
- Access type
- In which class the method is defined.

Also, `metaclass` can be constructed from the name of the class, without an instance, which can be an advantage in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, found it. Not very exciting - you can get a list of methods with the [methods](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/methods.html) command. So to check if an object has a method,

```
if any(strcmp(methods(o), 'myMethod'))
  o.myMethod();
end
```

Comment: that was my first thought, manually add a function `getMethods` to each class that returns all the methods, didn't mention because of the ugliness that would make. Nice to know that there already exists such a thing :p

btw, you can also use `ismember('myMethod',methods(o))`

Answer (score 2):

Very close! If you had written the function name a bit differently you would've stumbled upon the following built-in:

```
if ismethod(o, 'myMethod')
    o.myMethod();
end
```

Documentation: [ismethod](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismethod.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? You'd better have a good reason :p

Better make them inherit a general function from a superclass. Then you can just call that function for all of them, instead of looking up which class it is/checking if a function exists and then calling a function depending on the result (which is imo not very OO)

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like a strange thing to do - but if Matlab gives us heterogeneous collections, it would be a shame not to use them :-D. Since the method is only meaningful for some of the classes, it wouldn't be appropriate to have it in a superclass. Solving the problem in a proper OO way would require me to make changes to lots of classes so that I can differentiate between those with and without the method. I'd rather put in some hacky reflection-style in statement :-)

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to use the function [EXIST](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/exist.html) (along with the function [CLASS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/class.html)) to check if the method exists for the given class:

```
if exist(['@' class(o) '/myMethod'])
  o.myMethod();
end
```

Another option is to use the function [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) to perform the check like this:

```
if ~isempty(which([class(o) '/myMethod']))
  o.myMethod();
end
```

Comment: I think these only work for pre-7.6 classes, where there is a @class folder?